# Automate Simple Terminal Commands

Tags: macos, shell, automator

So here's an easy one for all you talented people out there. :) What I would like to do is create an Automator application that performs the following simple terminal commands when you drop a .command file on it, whose file name starts with "abc-123", and it's important that it throws an error if these criteria are not met and doesn't try to run the script.

```
chmod 777 file.command
./file.command
```

That's it! I don't have that much experience with this and having tried to Google my way to answer for 2 hours now, I thought I'd just ask, since it's probably quite simple...me hopes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this in bash shell :

```
for f in "$@"
do
    name=${f##*/}; 
    if [[ "$name" = abc-123*.command ]];then
        chmod 777 "$f"
        "$f"
    else
        exit 1;
    fi
done
```

Comment: What am I missing? :) If I run this, it completes the workflow but I never seen the Terminal window and it doesn't seem to run the .command file. Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is because the command is executed in Automator, not in the Terminal
If you want to see the result : check the button `Show this action when the workflow runs` in the options of the action "**Run Shell Script**".
If you want to see the result in the Terminal, use the open command --> `open "$f"`